# what is the right way of importing a maven project in Eclipse and run it as a Java project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I don't understand exactly what is the way of working with maven projects in Eclipse.
The problems I have are often with projects  I download from github. If I set the project myself it usually work, so I think I'm doing something different from the majority of people.

I'll try to detail a specific case:

1. I clone a repo, let's say: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2
2. In Eclipse I import "existing maven project"
3. The project has a "Maven nature" as indicated by M on the folder icon
4. I try to run java class with main from Eclipse. First strange thins is that the "Run As" menu doesn't have "Run as a Java application"
5. I have to configure the configuration manually. Now it runs, but strange things happens, like I can't edit the file as the "content assist" throw errors instead of giving the normal assists.
6. I notice that the project has no "source folder". So my first instinct is to add a Java nature or select src as source folder
7. So I add Java nature to the project. This is a disaster. It can compile anymore as it can find packages. All classes have errors. I try to play around setting source folders on /src or /src/main/java. Sometimes I fix the errors but I can't run (and now I have run as Java application) but when I run it can't load the class

So in the end, I'm a bit confused and I don't know if I explained clearly what I'm doing.
I think I would like to know in a simple way how people are doing it, rather than trying to correct my steps as I'm probably creating a mess myself.

Any help or suggestion welcome.
I'm using the last version of eclipse. I don't know which other tool's versions are relevant.

P.S. I also refresh,restart,clean rebuild the project often after touching things...but it doesn't get better

Comment: This is an issue that I've recently been pondering. My solution is to edit the .project file and add the missing elements directly.  I'm in an environment where we have lots of working projects, so there's always a correct example around, but I'm concerned about the "chicken and egg" problem. Do not edit the .classpath file, just the .project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is a build (management) tool. Simply spoken, its task is to create a JAR that can be used as a dependency/library by other projects or when running [`java -jar ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/java.html).

Running a project's code isn't part of it (apart from unit and integration tests code and by using non-default plugins for special situations). Running code is part of Eclipse (or any other IDE) with its *Run Configurations*.

Comment: well actually I'm able to run the project with run configuration. But the workflow doesn't feel right (I can edit correctly the project and have the usual java assists). A java project seems to have the classpath correctly configured to run in eclipse. A maven project does not. So I guess that my question is how to use projects like the one I mentioned in Eclipse. It's just one example, I have this problem very often, so probably I'm doing something wrong.